# Find overlapped rows in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to convert the following ascending data frame:

```
    start   end
0   100 500
1   400 700
2   450 580
3   750 910
4   920 940
5   1000    1200
6   1100    1300
```

into

```
    start   end
0   100 700
1   750 910
2   920 940
3   1000    1300
```

You may notice that rows 0:3 and 5:7 were merged, because these rows overlap or one row is subpart of another: actually, they have only one **start** and **end**.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom group with `shift` to identify the overlapping intervals and keep the first start and last end (or min/max if you prefer):

```
group = df['start'].gt(df['end'].shift()).cumsum()

out = df.groupby(group).agg({'start': 'first', 'end': 'last'})
```

output:

```
   start   end
0    100   580
1    750   910
2    920   940
3   1000  1300
```

intermediate `group`:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, but it works with overlapping rows, what to do if one row is subpart of another (in example row 2 is subpart of row 1)?

Comment: Then use `min`/`max` in place of `first`/`last`, ensure that the dataset is sorted by start

Comment: As for me that's magic, thanks a lot

Comment: No magic, `max` tells to get the max value for the end, `last` would mean the value of the last row. This is the same for partial overlap but different for strict subpart ;)